# Unable to build react-native 2 project to phone

Tags: android, sdk, react-native

I have my react-naive project completely setup and have been trying to run it to my phone but kep getting the following error when i run the

> react-native run-android

command.

Output:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/webshinobis/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

But i have checked the build tools and that file is right there. I have reinstalled the build tools for 23.0.1 but no change. any ideas to help? thanks.

Comment: did you follow all the instruction suggested in the official site? Take a look at [this docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 30):

Required libraries for 64-bit machines:

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries:

```
$sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

If you are running 64-bit Fedora:

```
$sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah thank you. I just followed this

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update
```

but I got an error said that couldn't found the package. Then I found answer in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637113/unable-to-locate-package-lib32bz2-1-0) . 
To summarize it , you should add architecture i386 like this

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update
```

this work for me very well.