# while running react native app i got this error

Tags: android, react-native

i already installed the build tools 23.0.1.but i got this error.

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: I believe this question has been answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355974/2218253 ANSWER = up vote
8
down vote
Required libraries for 64-bit machines:

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries:

$sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
If you are running 64-bit Fedora:

$sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to build react-native 2 project to phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181412/unable-to-build-react-native-2-project-to-phone)

Answer (score 2):

First make sure there is respective file exist or not, then please try this some action, that might solve your problem:

```
update latest android sdk tools
```

or

```
clean and rebuild after sync build.gradle
```

or

```
invalid cache /restart
```

if you are using jenkins then try this command in terminal: **sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1**

if all the option didn't work just follow this link: [Ant debug and ant release failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801483/ant-debug-and-ant-release-failed/30807140#30807140)  and ["aapt" IOException error=2, No such file or directory" why can't I build my gradle on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701405/aapt-ioexception-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory-why-cant-i-build-my-grad)

Hope this will help for you.